# Adding static routes to remote networks

Tags: routing, subnet, route, ip-routing

Having:

- My local machine (A)
- A remote router (B) who knows a remote network/subnet (X)
- My local machine's is located at the default router's (C) subnet, who know the remote router (B), but has no reference to the remote subnet (X)

Can I enter a static router in my local machine A to the subnet X via router B, without entering the route at C or any other routers at the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you do not have direct access to B. IP packet do not pass any information where it should go except final destination IP. So router has to determine its next hop only by his routing table and destination IP.